# MySQL - Selecting articles where upload date is between 01-01-2017 and 31-12-2017

Tags: mysql, sql, date

Need this to split up articles on my press release page in sections of years. So 2017, 2018, 2019 and so on. I just forgot how to propperly do this with a query. Any advice is much appreciated!

I tried (I also tried with an 'AS newName' and let the WHERE check for the newDate.):

```
SELECT *, DATE(`article_upload_date`, 'dd-mm-yyyy')
FROM articles
WHERE article_id = 1 AND
      DATE(article_upload_date) BETWEEN DATE('01-01-2017') AND DATE('31-12-2017')

SELECT *, DATE(`article_upload_date`, 'd-m-Y')
FROM articles
WHERE article_id = 1 AND
      DATE(article_upload_date) BETWEEN DATE('01-01-2017') AND DATE('31-12-2017')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the standard format for dates.  In MySQL, this looks like:

```
SELECT a.*, DATE_FORMAT(`article_upload_date`, '%d-%m-%Y')
FROM articles a
WHERE article_id = 1 AND
      DATE(article_upload_date) BETWEEN '2017-01-01' AND '2017-12-31';
```

Note the use of `DATE_FORMAT()` as well.

A better way to write the `WHERE` clause is:

```
WHERE article_id = 1 AND
      article_upload_date >= '2017-01-01' AND
      article_upload_date < '2018-01-01'
```

There is no need to use a function -- and using functions often prevents the use of indexes, affecting performance.

Comment: This worked, why do you use the article a, though? I won't be using multiple tables.

Comment: @ScottvanDuin . . . My habit is generally to write table aliases for all tables.

Comment: I see, I guess it does little harm, and comes in handy when you do have need of them.